# Customize a xml layout in a fragment - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, layout-inflater

I am new in Android programming.
I created the main Activity of my app style google shop ussing ActionBarSherlock and a NavigationTabs, with fragments, each referencing another activity (Fragment 1 Fragment 2, etc) and each fragment inflating a layout.

However, I'm used to create layouts in xml and then customize them in java. To put a different text depending on the time of day, or according to some data in a database, giving function to buttons, etc.. But in a Fragment Class, I can not even use setContentView to work with each text or button, and set the context for using my database is giving me problems.

How I can customize a xml layout in a fragment?
Or what would be the right thing to do?

Here my Fragment:

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more simple then you think. onCreateView instanciate au returns the view for your Fragment. As you said, in a simple Activity you set (and instanciate) the view with setContentView() and then you get your Views with findViewById().

findViewById() asks for the view to return the view item that you want, you can call it from your view before returning it. Like this:

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);

    // For example, getting a TextView
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
    // do your job

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

so far so good, you just need to use the view you are inflating to get everything.

here is an example

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);

Button b = (Button)v.findViewById(r.id.button1);

return v;
```

Answer (score 2):

inside `onActivityCreated` you could use:

```
View mView = getView();
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTextView);
```

where `theIdOfTextView` is declared inside `R.layout.menu`.

`getView()` returns the `View` you inflated inside `onCreateView`. You use it only after `onCreateView` has been executed